# Capture audio/video in NodeJS from hardware, steam it to frontend

Tags: node.js, video, camera, streaming, hardware

I am running a NodeJS/express server on a device (I have both BeagleBone and Raspberry Pi). This software needs to also access camera / microphone hardware directly, and send these audio/video streams to connected clients. I don't care at this point how the video /audio gets to the client, just that it gets there are can be decoded and played. The client in this case is a React Native Mobile app.

I want to take a moment to mention that this "device code" is NOT running in a browser. It's NodeJS / server side code. Consider this, for all intents and purposes, a "security" camera device. It sits somewhere and broadcasts what it sees and hears.

How do I:

a) Access video and audio streams in NodeJS

b) Get those streams into some kind of format that a web browser can play?

c) Decode the given video/audio in React Native?

d) Decode the video/audio in React (web)?

Working code examples would be greatly appreciate as opposed to explanations that lead me to dead ends when things don't work as expected.

I've been googling this for the last month and can not find answers. Can't even find someone else doing this same kind of project. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I can grab video / audio from browser and send it to clients over WebRTC. I can stream a video file over an HTTP route. I can use peerJs to connect clients peer to peer to avoid routing video/audio through a server. But I just can't seem to grab video from a camera in NodeJS and send it in the correct format / stream. It gets super confusing trying to figure out how to encode frames depending on video format, etc...I can't image someone hasn't done this 100 times already and published a nice functional npm package to handle this stuff.

Comment: Another example of what I'm trying to do would be like the Ring Doorbell. When the button is pressed it sends audio/video to a phone app. I want to do that, but peer to peer. Thanks

Comment: Hi @dror I was not able to find an acceptable solution. The browser seems to have this ability but not NodeJS. I have read that it’s possible to grab video with Python but never got that far. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason why you have not received an answer to this question (until now), is that your intended application operates ouside of the general used field of most Node.JS developers.

That is not to say that it can not be done. While not impossible for advanced coders in specialised fields, most developers would equip Node.JS with middleware as a mideary to operating systems and / or native software.

May I suggest something along the following lines for your approach:

OS: Linux

Why? Linux treats most inputs (Audio, Webcam etc.) "like files", which may come in handy in the next step.

Install FFMPEG: It is open source and perfectly suited for most audio / video conversion and compression, encoding and decoding tasks.

Since inputs are seen similarily to files in Linux, this synergises very well with the required "input files" in FFMPEG.

There are a couple of node libraries / modules on NPM and github, that can act as middleware and give you full control over FFMPEG. Combined with further middleware for webserver and the file system, you should be on your way to a feasable solution.

I am not a react user. Whether supplied by the framework or not - you will need a player module / library that will bring h264 etc. support to front end. Browsers nativly only support MJPEG video (compression of images only - no codecs implementing compression over a group of frames, with refrences to the adjacent frames or frame prediction).

MJPEG on the other hand can also be a processing (!) resource efficient choice and light weight in clients, when ever computing power is the bottleneck but abundant bandwith is available and / or low resolutions are acceptable.

Whether you need h264 in your backend or frontend, or MJPEG for either - FFMPEG can decode that very efficiently. I also find it rather "unbloated" when compared to popular alternatives with a lot of features and impressive GUI.

This is not meant as a complete guide, but pointer into a practically, workable direction. I hope it helps.